# Функция дозвона в java web app

Tags: java, spring, websocket, spring-mvc, web-apps

Как сделать функцию дозвона у веб приложении java. То есть: есть пользователь в системе, он выбирает другого пользователя в списке и вызывает его (как в skype). Видеотрасляцию сделал, нужно только функцию вызова сделать.. Но не знаю какю
Использую Spring 4, сервер - jetty. 
Возможно ли это сделать при помощи websocket-ов ? 
Кто стыкался с такой задачей подскажите как это сделать или подкиньте какую то инфу!